# dpdk number of mbuf and ring length

Tags: dpdk

I tried to use basic forwarding to receive packets, not need forward out.

To clarify some parameters: `#define NUM_MBUFS` used by

```
rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("MBUF_POOL", NUM_MBUFS * nb_ports, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
```

and `#define RX_RING_SIZE 65536` used by:

```
rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port, q, RX_RING_SIZE, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL, mbuf_pool);
```

I want to allocate more buffer for RX Ring. So I change to:

```
#define NUM_MBUFS 131071
#define RX_RING_SIZE 65536
```

But looks like does not work: get error: Segmentation fault (core dumped). What is conditional to set NUM_MBUF and RX_RING_SIZE, by the way, my TX_RING_SIZE is small, only 64, since do not need forward out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things:

1. First we should call [`rte_eth_dev_info_get()`](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a1fe7a16a3e301cdc10f2bac0ece160db) to get `rte_eth_dev_info` structure back.
2. Then we must make sure the arguments we pass to `rte_eth_rx_queue_setup()` are aligned with the limits the underneath PMD exposes, i.e. number of queues we try to configure is no more than `max_rx/tx_queues` and the number of descriptors is no more than `rx/tx_desc_lim.nb_max`

And last but not least. We should always check the return code of DPDK init functions, so we know where our program fails rather then wait for it to crash.

Comment: I rx_desc_lim.nb_max is 4096, but when I setup the queue: rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc and rte_eth_rx_queue_setup, it returns success (0). Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: @zigzag sure, that's fine. In the OP there was `RX_RING_SIZE` passed directly to the `rte_eth_rx_queue_setup()`, so I thought that might be the issue. Here is an [example of port initialization](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/examples_2l2fwd_2main_8c-example.html#a40). So with `rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc()` is is still crashing?

Comment: Yes, I called rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc(), but still crash.

Comment: @zigzag so, if `rte_eth_dev_adjust_nb_rx_tx_desc` and `rte_eth_rx_queue_setup` work fine and return 0, it means it crashes later, right? You have to provide a complete example or debug where it crashes [as described in DPDK Programmer's Guide.](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/dev_kit_root_make_help.html#compiling-for-debug)